# Accessing an actor's isolated state from within a SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, concurrency, swiftui

I'm trying to understand a design pattern for accessing the isolated state held in an actor type from within a SwiftUI view.

Take this naive code:

```swift
actor Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var num: Int = 0
    
    func updateNumber(_ newNum: Int) {
        self.num = newNum
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.num)") // <-- Compiler error: Actor-isolated property 'num' can not be referenced from the main actor
        Button("Update number") {
            Task.detached() {
                await model.updateNumber(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Understandably I get the compiler error `Actor-isolated property 'num' can not be referenced from the main actor` when I try and access the isolated value. Yet I can't understand how to display this data in a view. I wonder if I need a ViewModel that observes the actor, and updates itself on the main thread, but get compile time error `Actor-isolated property '$num' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context`.

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let model: Model
    @Published var num: Int
    let cancellable: AnyCancellable
    
    init() {
        let model = Model()
        self.model = model
        self.num = 0
        self.cancellable = model.$num
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { self.num = $0 }
    }
    
}
```

Secondly, imagine if this code did compile, then I would get another error when clicking the button that the interface is not being updated on the main thread...again I'm not sure how to effect this from within the actor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer might not suite all use cases.

In my case, I want the `ObservableObject` to remain an `actor`, but access one of its property from a SwiftUI view. So I added `@MainActor` only to that property.

This means that property also needs to be updated only from the main thread as shown below.

```swift
actor Model: ObservableObject {
  @MainActor @Published var num: Int = 0

  func updateNumber(_ newNum: Int) {
    Task { @MainActor in 
      self.num = newNum
    }
  }

  // all other properties and functions will remain isolated to the actor
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `MainActor` on your view model (named `Model`) indicating that all dispatching in it be on main thread (of course assuming you will use new swift concurrency system for it).

So it would look like

```
@MainActor 
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var num: Int = 0

    func updateNumber(_ newNum: Int) {
        self.num = newNum
    }
}
```

*Note: I'd recommend to make all updates inside class, because someone in some place might forget to update it in right way.*

Comment: Thank you. In your note, do I understand it would be better to write: 
```func updateNumber(_ newNum: Int) { Task.detached() { await model.updateNumber(newNum) }}```

Comment: Am I also correct in understanding that in a SwiftUI app all syncronisation would happen via `@MainActor`, and therefore one wouldn't create any types using `actor`?

Comment: @PhilipPegden - I know this is an old question, but, no, not all synchronization would happen on the main actor. Sure,  various `ObservableObject` which exist solely for the purposes of updating the UI (e.g., view models) might be on the main actor, but that does not mean that all synchronization throughout the app would be on the main actor. Very few of our types need to be isolate to the main actor.