# How do I reference an `actor`'s properties from a `Button`'s action or `Binding`?

Tags: swift, swiftui, actor, swift5

I have an actor like this, which performs long, complex work constantly in the background:

```swift
actor Foo {
    var field: [Bar]

    struct Bar {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do I update its `field` from a SwiftUI view?

I tried this, but got these errors:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject
    var foo: Foo


    var body: some View {
        Text("Field count is \(foo.field.count)") //  Actor-isolated property 'field' can not be referenced from the main actor

        Button("Reset foo") {
            foo.field = [] //  Actor-isolated property 'field' can not be mutated from the main actor
        }
    }
}
```

How do I access & mutate my `actor` from within a SwiftUI view?

Comment: I don't think actors are supposed to be used directly from the UI layer. You might need an intermediate for that, e.g. an `ObservableObject` to make sure the value of the label is kept in sync with the actor state.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68713750/12299030?

Comment: Right, forgot about the main actor :p

Comment: But I want this actor to perform background work; isn't that the point of having it be an `actor`?  Or perhaps I misunderstood. @Asperi

Comment: I see you updated the question with the additional details regarding the background work, in this case I think your only solution is what I suggested in my other comment.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with accessing the `field` property of the actor is that it requires and `await` call, if the access is made outside of the actor. This means a suspension point in your SwiftUI code, which means that when the SwiftUI code resumes, it might no longer be executing on the main thread, and that's a big problem.

If the actor doesn't do background work, then Asperi's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68713750/12299030) that uses @MainAction would nicely work, as in that case the SwiftUI accesses happen on the main thread.

But if the actor runs in the background, you need another sync point that runs code on the main thread, that wraps the `Foo` actor, and which is consumed by your view:

```swift
actor Foo {
    private(set) var field: [Bar]
    
    func updateField(_ field: [Bar]) {
        self.field = field
    }

    struct Bar {
        // ...
    }
}

class FooModel: ObservableObject {
    private let foo: Foo
    
    @Published var field: [Foo.Bar] = [] {
        didSet {
            Task { await foo.updateField(field) }
        }
    }
    
    init(foo: Foo) {
        self.foo = foo
        Task { self.field = await foo.field }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject
    var foo: FooModel
```

However this is only half of the story, as you'll need to also send notifications from `Foo` to `FooModel` when the value of `field` changes. You can use a `PassthroughSubject` for this:

```swift
actor Foo {
    var field: [Bar] {
        didSet { fieldSubject.send(field) }
    }
    
    private let fieldSubject: PassthroughSubject<[Bar], Never>
    let fieldPublisher: AnyPublisher<[Bar], Never>
    
    init() {
        field = ... // initial value
        fieldSubject = PassthroughSubject()
        fieldPublisher = fieldSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func updateField(_ field: [Bar]) {
        self.field = field
    }

    struct Bar {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and subscribe to the published from the model:

```swift
class FooModel: ObservableObject {
    private let foo: Foo
    
    @Published var field: [Foo.Bar] = [] {
        didSet {
            Task { await foo.updateField(field) }
        }
    }
    
    init(foo: Foo) {
        self.foo = foo
        Task { self.field = await foo.field }
        foo.fieldPublisher.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).assign(to: &$field)
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's a non-trivial amount of code to be written, due to the fact that actors run on arbitrary threads, while your SwiftUI code (or any UI code in general) must be run only on the main thread.

Comment: Oh my goodness that is amazingly complex... I thought `actor`s were supposed to simplify things, but it just seems to me that going back to a `class` with a dedicated `DispatchQueue` is the best answer right now. Thank you for helping me understand!

Comment: @KyLeggiero note that you'd run into similar problems with you'll want your GCD-based class to do its work on a background queue. Race conditions can appear on the `field` property, when consumed by the UI.